# Microsoft Teams Powershell Function Set-CsExternalAccessPolicy not found

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have installed the Microsoft Teams module successfully, but the function Set-CsExternalAccessPolicy is not recognized as a function in PowerShell. It's really frustrating because all the other functions and command lets from that module are working, except that one. I am even using the latest version of that module 2.3.1 . Please help. I have even uninstalled and reinstalled the module. I checked the spelling of the function many times too.

Comment: That's a Lync function. What is it you're trying to do? `Set-CsExternalAccessPolicy`  is for Skype.

Comment: I am trying to edit the policy so that these two requirements are true:                     Users can communicate with other Skype for Business and Teams users
Users can communicate with Skype users,                                                                                     I believe that the top one can be set true by enforcing the Set-CsExternalAccessPolicy. And I checked this command is a function of the module Microsoft Teams module, so it should be recognized. What's a lync function?

Comment: Lync is Skype. That function is apart of the Skype snap-in last I remember.

Comment: It was, but Microsoft brought it to the Microsoft Teams module.

Comment: Try reloading it?

Comment: I have tried uninstalling the module and reinstalling it, but it doesn't work. What else can I do?

Comment: Check `Get-Module MicrosoftTeams` to be sure that you have version `2.0.0` or newer. Skype Cmdlets are implemented in this module since version `2.0.0`

Comment: I am using verrsion 2.3.1 and then I even downgraded to 2.0.0 and still it gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you even find a solution for this? I am having exactly the same issue...

Comment: nope, garfield185

Comment: I am also running into this error while attempting to follow the instructions in this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/edu-parents-app

Comment: I was able to fix the error by following oshihirii's steps here (uninstalling the module and re-installing the pre-release version): https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/6143